# Flask Custom Filter Template not working

Tags: templates, flask, jinja2

I'm attempting to add my own custom filter to my templates in a Flask app that I'm writing.  The goal is to have a display that shows a "days ago" time for posts (similar to what Twitter does).

My **views.py** file contains the following:

```
import datetime

@app.template_filter('days_ago') 
def days_ago(t=datetime.timedelta(0)):
    diff = (datetime.datetime.now() - t)
    return diff.days

@app.route('/posts/<id>')
def view_post(id):
    p = models.Post.query.get(id)
    return render_template('view_post.html', 
                    post = p)
```

And my **view_post.html** template contains:

```
...
<p>{{ post.created_at | days_ago }} days old</p>
...
```

I keep running across this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'NoneType'
```

I've attempted to have the parameter `t` default to `datetime` and `timedelta` objects, but I still get the same error.  Any leads?  Thanks for your time in advance!

Comment: Oops!  Sorry, this was a typo.  I've edited my question to reflect this.  Thanks for the note!

Comment: What does `Post` look like? Are you sure `created_at` isn't `None`?

Comment: Hi dirn, I traced the error.  Coming from a Ruby background, I expected an empty string '' for post.created_at to have my filter's function default to the default value set for t, and not override it with 'None.'  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Default values are only used when the argument isn't provided in the call.